# Serverless Cognito User Pool authorizer

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless-framework

I want to use my Cognito User Pool as the authorizer for all my lambda functions deployed through the Serverless Framework and API Gateway.

The [Serverless docs](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/apigateway#http-endpoints-with-custom-authorizers) mention that this is possible as follows, which exposes claims at `event.requestContext.authorizer.claims`:

```
functions:
  create:
    handler: posts.create
    events:
      - http:
          path: posts/create
          method: post
          authorizer:
            arn: arn:aws:cognito-idp:us-east-1:xxx:userpool/us-east-1_ZZZ
            scopes:
              - my-app/read
```

Or, if you want more control of which attributes are exposed as claims, use the following implementation which exposes claims at `events.cognitoPoolClaims`:

```
functions:
  create:
    handler: posts.create
    events:
      - http:
          path: posts/create
          method: post
          integration: lambda
          authorizer:
            arn: arn:aws:cognito-idp:us-east-1:xxx:userpool/us-east-1_ZZZ
            claims:
              - email
              - nickname
```

I have a few questions about this and I'm attempting to find the answers online, but the terms are all commonly-used and it's hard to know what to search for and recognize the correct answer. The docs also seem to show a few examples, but never specifies all the available options (as far as I've seen). I'd appreciate some clarification on the following or a link to the docs where it may explain some of this in more detail:

1. What scopes are available? (e.g. `scopes: my-app/read`)
2. What is the difference between exposing the claims at `event.requestContext.authorizer.claims` vs `events.cognitoPoolClaims`?
3. Will this implementation work with `httpApi` functions, instead of `http` like the docs show?